# Java: if, else and return

Tags: java

I am writing a method which contains if else statements, but also a return keyword. Now, I'm writing something like this:

```
public boolean deleteAnimal(String name) throws Exception{
    if(name == null || name.trim().isEmpty())
        throw new Exception("The key is empty");
    else if(exists(name)){
        hTable.remove(name);
    }
    else throw new Exception("Animal doesn't exist");

    return hTable.get(name) == null;
}
```

I'm new in java and this is my first time trying to learn a programming language. I read that the 'else' statement excecutes always if the if condition is false.

Now, if these are false:

```
if(name == null || name.trim().isEmpty())
        throw new Exception("The key is empty");
    else if(exists(name)){
        hTable.remove(name);
}
```

Shouldn't the else part always excecute?

```
else throw new Exception("Animal doesn't exist");
```

I noticed this since this method is returning true/false, and it seems like it's ignoring the else part, even when the conditions above it are false.

Comment: Would you mind posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The `else` will fire if all other conditionals--i.e. `if`, `if else`--are `false`. It does not *always* execute. Think about it like this:  `If it is raining, then I carry my umbrella; else if it is snowing, then I wear my parka; else I wear shorts and a tshirt.`

Comment: These are not nested. They are sequenced. Your second else goes with your second if. If you want `"Animal doesn't exist"`, `exists(name)` needs to be false, not the conditions in the first if-condition.

Comment: @KennethK. The OP asked if those (the other conditionals) were false, would else always execute and that would be yes

Comment: @AndrewL No, he wrote if the `if` condition was false, not all other conditionals.

Comment: I tested it and if both ifs are false, it does throw the Exception.

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8oIqDyjcpnu56QzX): the exception was thrown.

Comment: @KennethK. He asks if `if` and `else if` return false. There's a weird indentation issue

Answer (score 1):

Without the knowledge about the rest of the code `exists(String name)` and the type of `hTable` (`Map<String,? extends Object>`) I need to guess:

If exits returns true, the else if statement evaluates to true. The line hTable.remove(name) will be executed. The else-branch is not invoked, because the `else if` was. Now the last line will `return hTable.get(name) == null;`

I think it will return true, because the hTable will return null.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to add comments to your snippet to help you understand the flow:

```
public boolean deleteAnimal(String name) throws Exception{
    if(name == null || name.trim().isEmpty())
        throw new Exception("The key is empty");   //Executes if 'name' is null or empty

    else if(exists(name)){
        hTable.remove(name);       // Excecutes if 'name' is not null and not empty and the exists() returns true
    }

    else 
        throw new Exception("Animal doesn't exist");  //Excecutes if 'name' is not null and not empty and the exists() returns false

    return hTable.get(name) == null;    //The only instance when this is possible is when the 'else if' part was executed
}
```

Hope the comments helps you understand the flow!

With this in mind, the answer to your question is 'yes'.